# CSS3 {text-align: start} for Japanese top to bottom content

Tags: css, text-align

CSS `{text-align: start}` is behaving as `{text-align: end}` in Japanese top to bottom text [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9xdgeafw/1/).

Can anyone with some clarity in Japanese text explain this behavior or is this a bug in chrome/firefox?

My expectation was that, text with value 'start' and 'left' should align to top and text with value 'end' and 'right' should  align to bottom as this Japanese text is written top to bottom.

As you can see 'left', 'right' and 'center' behave as expected, but 'start' and 'end' seems to have reversed in their behavior.

Comment: If you are giving -1 to this question, please care to explain in comments, what is not clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align` for ``start and `end` works according to the `direction`. if you set `direction: rtl;` it works the opposite but if set `direction: ltr;` works correctly.

```css
#container-for-ltr-text {
  direction: ltr;
}

#container-for-rtl-text {
  direction: rtl;
}

#align-to-start-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: start;
}

#align-to-end-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: end;
}

#align-to-start-ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: start;
}

#align-to-end-ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container-for-ltr-text">Hello world</div>
    <div id="container-for-rtl-text">ハローワールド</div>
    
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">direction rtl</h3>
    <div id="align-to-start-rtl">text align start in direction rtl</div>
    <div id="align-to-end-rtl">text align end in direction rtl</div>
    
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">direction ltr</h3>
    <div id="align-to-start-ltr">text align start in direction ltr</div>
    <div id="align-to-end-ltr">text align end in direction ltr</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

if you want it always work correctly use `right` and 'left' for set `text-align`

```css
#container-for-ltr-text {
  direction: ltr;
}

#container-for-rtl-text {
  direction: rtl;
}

#align-to-right-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}

#align-to-left-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}

#align-to-right-ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: right;
}

#align-to-left-ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container-for-ltr-text">Hello world</div>
    <div id="container-for-rtl-text">ハローワールド</div>
    
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">direction rtl</h3>
    <div id="align-to-right-rtl">text align right in direction rtl</div>
    <div id="align-to-left-rtl">text align left in direction rtl</div>
    
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">direction ltr</h3>
    <div id="align-to-right-ltr">text align right in direction ltr</div>
    <div id="align-to-left-ltr">text align left in direction ltr</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

so, if you want to set generally direction, you have to set it in `body` tag:
for example:

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

I hope be useful

Comment: Yup, just figured that out see my answer. Thanks for the help. I will mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

`{direction: rtl;}` was causing the issue. Removing it fixed the issue.